# When is the use of std::ref necessary?

Tags: c++, c++11, portability, correctness, reference-wrapper

Consider:

```
std::tuple<int , const A&> func (const A& a) 
{
  return std::make_tuple( 0 , std::ref(a) );
}
```

Is the `std::ref` required for writing correct and portable code? (It compiles fine without it)

Background:

If I remove `std::ref` my code builds fine without any warnings (`g++-4.6 -Wall`), but doesn't run correctly.

In case of interest the definition of `A`:

```
struct A {
  std::array<int,2> vec;
  typedef int type_t;

  template<typename... OPs,typename... VALs>
  A& operator=(const std::pair< std::tuple<VALs...> , std::tuple<OPs...> >& e) {
    for( int i = 0 ; i < vec.size() ; ++i ) {
      vec[i] = eval( extract(i,e.first) , e.second );
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Also nicely asked and answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530460/what-would-be-a-hello-world-example-for-stdref

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- `make_tuple(0, a)` makes a `tuple<int, A>`.
- `make_tuple(0, ref(a))` makes a `tuple<int, reference_wrapper<A>>`.
- You can also say `tuple<int, A&> t(0, a);` for a tuple you can't make with `make_tuple`, or use `std::tie`.

Comment: So, it should throw an error if `ref` is removed. Why does it not, any idea?

Comment: @Frank: A tuple can be constructed from anything humanly possible. You just end up returning a reference to a local variable, namely a local copy of `a`. With `ref` you return a wrapped reference to the original function argument.

Comment: @Frank: in other words, you should say `return std::tuple<int, A const &>(0, a);`.

Comment: I see. But then, as you say, a `tuple<int,A>` is created/returned. How can this be returned given the `tuple<int,const A&>` as the return type?

Comment: I did :-) That's twisted. In the function body `a` refers to the instance passed into the function. But when using `make_tuple` it is treated as a local variable. That's error-prone. Any advice how to avoid such erroneous practice? ;-)

Comment: @Frank: Know your way around how `std::tuple` works? It's a fascinating little template that touches on so many corners of C++...

Comment: Strictly speaking `std::make_tuple(ref(a))` would result in an `std::tuple<A const&>`, not `std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<const A>>`. Many parts of the Standard library that decay their arguments are special-cased to 'decay' `std::reference_wrapper<T>` to `T&`. They can be identified because they're often specified in terms of `std::decay` even though `std::decay` itself doesn't do that conversion (somewhat frustratingly).

Answer (score 49):

One of the example where `std::ref` is necessary:

```
void update(int &data)  //expects a reference to int
{
    data = 15;
}
int main()
{
    int data = 10;

    // This doesn't compile as the data value is copied when its reference is expected.
    //std::thread t1(update, data);         

    std::thread t1(update, std::ref(data));  // works

    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The `std::thread` constructor copies the supplied values, without converting to the expected argument type (which is *reference* type in this case, see`update()`). So we need to **wrap the arguments that really needs to be references** in `std::ref`.

Comment: std::thread t1(update, data); will compiles well, but the problem is that it does not change the value of the data.

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf It doesn't compile! The variable "data" must be wrapped in std::ref(data) to generate a rvalue being passed to t1. You would be right, if the parameter "data" in function "update" would be of type "const int&". But then std::thread would internally copy the argument and actually not reference the passed variable "data".

Answer (score 26):

`std::ref` does not make a reference, so in your code sample it doesn't do what you expect. `std::ref` creates an object that behaves similarly to a reference. It may be useful, for example,  when you want to instantiate a functor, and pass a reference-like version of it to a standard library algorithm. Since algorithms take functors by value, you can use `std::ref` to wrap the functor.

Answer (score 3):

Answering the question in the title (`When is the use of std::ref necessary?`): Another case where `std::ref` is useful is when looping over a list of references to objects and modify them:

```
std::vector<int> v1, v2;
  
void test() {
  for (std::vector<int>& vv : 
    // Compiles
    { std::ref(v1), std::ref(v2) } 
  
    // Compiler rejects this with:
    //   binding reference of type 'vector<...>' to value of 
    //   type 'const vector<...>' drops 'const' qualifier 
    // { v1, v2} 
  ) {
      vv.push_back(3);
  }
}
```

Without using `std::ref` in the list, the objects are treated as `const` and can't be modified (see also https://godbolt.org/z/Ta6YM31KM).